# Character randomly rotating on the X and Z axes even thought Rigidbody constraints are enabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics, rigid-bodies

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

class FirstPersonCamera : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

    public Transform playerTransform;
    public Transform weaponTransform;

    private float xRotation = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        UnityEngine.Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked; //Hides the cursor and locks it to the center
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);
        weaponTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);

        playerTransform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f, mouseX, 0.0f));

        //playerTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0.0f,mouseX,0.0f));

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            UnityEngine.Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I'm using for player looking (mouse controls) and this keeps happening:
[image: Issue]

even though I have rigidbody X and Z rotations locked. The issue mainly seems to arise when using keyboard controls and mouse together. Here is the playerMove code as well: https://codeshare.io/wnzrYj . It shouldn't be doing anything with rotation.

I've tried removing the playerTransform.Rotate and the issue seems to disappear. I've also tried rotating the gameObject via the rigidbody but that doesn't seem to rotate the body at all.

Comment: As soon as physics is involved you don't want to go through the `Transform` component at all but always through the `Rigidbody` instead and e.g. use `MoveRotation` in `FixedUpdate` otherwise you might break collision detection anyway

Answer (score 0):

You're causing the rotations yourself.  You've added the xRotation, which will affect the pitch, but then you use Transform.Rotate, which works locally.  That means that when pitched, your Rotate is no longer around the world's Y axis, but rather around the object's pitched Y-axis, adding rotation to axes you don't want.

The easiest way to solve this is to build your hierarchy properly to make sure that the rotations are applied in the order you want.  I usually go with something like:

```
Root -> YawPivot -> Body -> PitchPivot -> Head/Camera
```

The Root object would have the translations (offsets/movement) applied to it.  The YawPivot is only rotated around the Y axis.  And the PitchPivot is only rotated around the X axis (and is usually located around the neck or head area).